# Tufte page numbering on first page of new chapter

Tags: numbering, tufte

I am using the Tufte-Book style but have very short chapters. The page number is not added to the first page of a new chapter so I end up with very few numbered pages at all.

Question: How can I add page numbering to every page of the chapter including the first page of each chapter?

Thanks in advance,
David.

Comment: This should work: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}`.

Comment: Thank you so much Benjamin! You solution gave me exactly what I was after.

Comment: How can I add the page number to the first page without including the chapter of the document?

Comment: @Benjamin Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @scientiffic If you have another question then please ask it and do not comment it.

Answer (score 2):

Customize the page style so that every page style is `plain`

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```