# Chicago Author-Date in tufte-book Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, tufte, chicago-style

I'm trying to format a bibliography in a tufte-book document in Chicago Author-Date style. There are no citations in the document itself. Can anyone help? Here is the syntax:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\input{tex/0_theground}
\input{tex/goldstein}
\input{tex/patterson}
\input{tex/barrett}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bookpages=false,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bib/test}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sure thing: http://pastebin.com/hPHEPkU8

Comment: Please consider adding the full MWE here instead of on pastebin. You might also want to read up on [what makes a good MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\addbibresource` (you need to include the file extension `.bib`) instead of `\bibliography`, and you have to print the bibliography with `\printbibliography`.

Also, you need to call `tufte-book` with the class option `nobib`in order to make `biblatex` work.

The result should look like this:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[authordate,
            backend=biber,          % You need to run biber instead of bibtex
            bookpages=false,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            url=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}   % You need to include the file extension, e.g. ".bib"

\begin{document}
    Test

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Odd, now the bibliography has vanished completely http://pastebin.com/9uCbXthp

Comment: @christopher You'll need to run Biber on your file, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Comment: @christopher I also notice that you wrote `\addbibresource{bib/test}`. You need to include the file extension (`.bib`) (this is exactly contrary to what you do in `\bibliography` - there you leave out the extension `.bib`), so it would probably be `\addbibresource{bib/test.bib}`. Make sure that Biber is allowed to access the folder `bib` or put the file into the same directory as your main file.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. When I try to compile the test that DG proposed: `\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{document}
    Test

   \nocite{*}
   \bibliography
     
\end{document}` I get these errors from bibtest.blg: `I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibtest.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bibtest.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bibtest.aux`

Comment: @christopher I should have been a bit clearer in my comment above, you need to run Biber and not BibTeX. (The `.blg` file shows clearly that you are running BibTeX.) If you do that from an editor, you can check out the second link from my comment above for help on setting up Biber.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I ran biber from the terminal! The only trouble is that now the bibliography is gone from the TOC and there are no page numbers. Any tips there?

Comment: @christopher Use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`. The page number is always missing on the very first page of a chapter. If you don't want that [have a look here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290310/35864).